# Redhat linux terminal profile location

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, redhat-enterprise-linux, .profile

I am using VNC to connect to a remote machine where I used to set preferences for the terminal like my own keyboard shortcuts.

Can anybody tell me where these profile configuration is getting saved ?

The reason is, sometimes, I may loose the VNC and later I may have to create new VNC session for that red-hat server and I am loosing my terminal profile information.

Because of this, I am forced to do my custom terminal profile settings redundantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the config file is depending on the terminal application being used. If you are using Gnome Terminal the settings are stored in `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Thanks mtak!. :) I am using Gnome terminal only and able to see the configuration and profile information in the path mentioned by you.